# Oracle Forms Execute_query giving FRM-40737 error

Tags: oracleforms, oracle-ebs

I am getting an error

> FRM - 40737 - illegal restricted procedure GO_BLOCK in
>   WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD trigger.

My Code is

```
IF event_name = 'WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD'
      THEN
         IF (form_name = 'OEXOEORD' AND block_name = 'ORDER')
         THEN
            -- call procedure to validate and cascade the ship method code.
            cascade_ship_method;
         execute_query;
         END IF;
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Thank you Sergii Zhevzhyk .. My Question looks much better now  :)

Comment: Is it the whole code?

Comment: No Sergii.. cascade_ship_method is a separate procedure. Without the 'execute_query' form is not refreshing, after putting execute_query am getting the mentioned error. in some forum I found we should not use 'execute_query' under 'WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM' . is it applicable for 'WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Oracle Forms has two types of built-in procedures - restricted and unrestricted. Some triggers enable restricted procedures, some not (see Oracle Forms help, every trigger has information which procedures it enables).

Trigger WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM fires for example when user moves cursor from one record to the other (this is called navigation). In this case it leaves one record and enters other. There is fired following chain of triggers

- WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM
- WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD
- POST-ITEM
- POST-RECORD
- PRE-RECORD
- PRE-ITEM

If any of this trigger fails, navigation is canceled and cursor returns to the original item. If you call any procedure, which starts new navigation (like GO_BLOCK), Oracle Forms would not be able to manage first navigation.

This is, why some procedures are restricted.

Comment: Hi Petr... so how this 'refresh' can be achieved ? Scenario is "When ever there is a change in the header shipping method , we need to call a procedure to the cascading to lines then REFRESH it " . I did all the this except 'refresh'. Kindly Help

Comment: refresh records is common problem in oracle forms. We use two approaches. If we need to refresh one record after database trigger changed it, we refresh it in POST-UPDATE or POST-INSERT trigger. We simply select new values into form items. In these triggers we don't change record status. If we need to refresh whole block or cascade of blocks, we start a timer and do a refresh in WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED trigger

Comment: Ok Petr.. thank you for your input. let me try Post-update or Post - Insert option. thanks alot  :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be relevant with content of `cascade_ship_method`. When I got this error, I had missed an apostrophe in the `SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY` statement. When I fixed, it worked. This is the correct structure in my code block:

```
SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY (
                  'TABLE_A',
                  default_where,
                     'column_a= '
                  || ''''
                  || variable
                  || '''');
```